# How can i access remote machine broswer in web application - Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I got a project requirement to scrape website data. Website needs user credentials to scrape data. However user not comfortable to share password and store in database. I have seen similar application which user can connect to their own account but providing username and password (https://zopto.com/home1#features). And the browser session will open in server without closing it. Each user will get their own Private machine.

**How can we achieve this?  Is this possible?**

1. Create a Aws Workspace on demand
2. We open browser and the site lets say helloworld.com
3. We shoe helloworld.com login page in client machine in a pop up window?
4. User can login  to the application and close the pop up
5. Then we can scrape from helloworld.com in aws workspace we created for that user.

**Technology** : Python, Django, React, Selenium.

Please share your thoughts.